# puppeteer - scrape contents in infinite scroll pages stop working after overflow is set

Tags: javascript, css, instagram, puppeteer

I'm doing a coding exercise with nodejs and puppeteer. I want to make a simple Instagram scraping script. I've tried using axios and HTTP module but with that solution I was unable to fetch all the contents because of the cursors used for pagination. I've then switched to puppeteer and I'm trying with this code

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

let imagesLinks = [];

function extractItems() {
  const extractedElements = document.querySelectorAll('img');
  const items = [];
  for (let element of extractedElements) {
    items.push(element.src);
  }
  console.log(items);
  return items;
}

async function scrapeInfiniteScrollItems(page, extractItems, itemTargetCount, scrollDelay = 1000){
  let items = [];
  try {
    let previousHeight;
    while (items.length < itemTargetCount) {
      items = await page.evaluate(extractItems);
      previousHeight = await page.evaluate('document.body.scrollHeight');
      await page.evaluate('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)');
      await page.waitForFunction(`document.body.scrollHeight > ${previousHeight}`);
      await page.waitFor(scrollDelay);
    }
  } catch(e) { }
  return items;
}

(async() => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false, 
    //args: ['--incognito']
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  page.setViewport({height: 680, width: 1280});

  await page.goto('https://instagram.com/username');
  page.waitForSelector('.aOOlW.bIiDR').then( el => el.click() );

  // Scroll and extract items from the page.
  const items = await scrapeInfiniteScrollItems(page, extractItems, 100);

  console.log(items);
})();
```

When I run the script, puppeteer will open two chromium tabs, one is blank and the second will open the link passed to the `page.goto` function. Is possible to set puppeteer to open only the tab that will display the desired URL? Another problem I'm facing is with the Instagram infinite scroll. I'm able to click on the cookie popup that is displayed after the page is loaded, the script then will start to grab the images links but after some scrolls it will stop scrolling because a login popup will appear and the `body` will get the `overflow: hidden` property. How can I prevent that the script stops scrolling until the page reaches the bottom? Is it possible to remove the CSS property and after this let the script continue scrolling to scrape contents?

Comment: First question: `const [page] = await browser.pages();` should work. Second question, I'm pretty sure instragram doesn't let you just hide the modal and go back to infinite scrolling. The API likely completely stops delivering feed data to force you to login, which you could do.

Comment: @ggorlen I will try your suggestion about the first question. For the second question, the problem isn't the popup but the script itslef. I think that there is a mistake in the code that will cause the problem. I can say this because if a profile have 300 images shared, the script will continue scrolling also with the popup opened and will arbitrary stop scroll. The popup can be closed by hiding it using css and by removing the `overflow: hidden`, and the api will continue serving contents